# Adding a custom post type meta field to rss

Tags: posts, customization

So I added my videos custom post type to my rss feed via this code.

```
//Add videos custom post type
function myfeed_request($qv) {
if (isset($qv['feed']) && !isset($qv['post_type']))
    $qv['post_type'] = array('post', 'videos');
return $qv;
}
add_filter('request', 'myfeed_request');
```

Is there a way to add a custom post type meta field to the output.

Example:

```
Title
Post meta field (in this case a video)
Post data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter `the_content_feed`:

```
add_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wpse_96342_add_video' );

function wpse_96342_add_video( $feed_content )
{
    // fetch post meta
    // add to content

    return $feed_content;
}
```